# TypeScript smart generic

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

I don't even know how to google this question, so I'm not sure what the best explanation for it would be. Let me just show an example.

Let's say that I have a type like this:

```
type SomeType<Prop, Model> = {
  [value: string]: {
    loadMany: (ids: readonly Prop[]) => readonly Model[];
    getProp: (ids: readonly Prop[]) => readonly Model[]
  }
}
```

Now, here's the trick: `Prop` and `Model` are generic not on the `SomeType` level but rather on the field level. That is, I want to do something like this:

```
const args: SomeType = {
  id: {
    loadMany: (ids: readonly number[]) => new Array(ids.length).fill(new User(0, 'sup')), 
    getProp: (user: User) => user.id,
  },
  username: {
    loadMany: (ids: readonly string[]) => new Array(ids.length).fill(new User(0, 'sup')), 
    getProp: (user: User) => user.username,
  }
}
```

How can I define `SomeType` to make it happen?

---

For context, here's a TS playground with some more details about why I need this: [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBO0DeAoa0CWATAXNAHYCuAtgEbIDcm0JiSRYZChEALktkQOa11gAeyKckJYByFIAFHkKlKyADT1GzVuy49eASjR0sHABbYIAOjzQAvDly0sR0xYbINCG2rcsED6AF90QPQOAE8ABw8AEQQAMx5sDmwRADESIklk0QAeAAUkIXDVAFkhXAQQAD5PDCwQITBcYrAiUMIZcILwgDUwEBIECEIkBEaREFDofMKAbQBdfWtqkbGiCehS8pB5v14EDmnw9rIyisJNisXqw9p-AVBIGCiwDjAAGQbypDyuktOqgxYWLpTIiIbQGLxIiJLJpDJJME-Qp-LaVARYYSiLgSKSyYHwrLgyEJBFEOGgnKHFEVSr6WqOExmcz4ikwWws0kQPyBYKYzjQMBIXhswF2Qj0uqfZqtdp4cErXDjSaKKhIeZXYgIADu0AAgkgkGBQnJcBYQAg+CZdMzsCAQDIiNq4IwZAAGVQAcggJHCHt0ulUAHpA9AtbaQALJCQ+ut6o0vEgYBRJgBJKIQQzQPYHLrtVxIQjwZAa-OWXDKOj+CtYfPucWZuNNFptaAm+WjRVrSZiHTqmzVR06-WG41y8zmy3Ga3xO0Op1F2Tu6Ben1+gPQYOh8ORjjRu2TRsJpOTWs+DOOLP7Q55xiFxglxjmU+sasBILodCBgBUX8wX+gADqxgvNAADWPC4NAQixNAAAqEQIAAysA3DhBw0BkGAvDYMA0DAC00Apl40BSCRCEkcYHiYgAbsgEBZNAnSFMgEwAPx-oG6AcgxKGjBwCDPK8HyNHRMiNsg+rCnSdAjLuTDQAA8hQABWCCSOYFraIMYmfBJQoQNaIy4BICAyDIYDAMAqgzKBCChKo3Fggs-ailgFnADZdlzJ4g4Qi87y6XiIKcrofhYLJJDye53KqKg-i6O+6B8uhuD+cJXwirxLwCWlgUQOZ+mhegqVCXlZbUBuIYQMYQgkCAkFUH5pUid8KoqM6yCVMVuUtS46g+BVm7VbV9XQI1gkBS12Q9nwqgLpUQA).

Comment: There is no specific `SomeType` that works this way.  You can make a generic constraint instead.  Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mxDPKm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining it; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yup that's perfect, thank you, @jcalz! Would be great if you could explain some syntax as well, especially the `Entries` definition and type inference.